# Extjs Pie Chart on click direct to new page

Tags: extjs, web, onclick, extjs4.1, pie-chart

I have an Extjs pie chart right now and I want each piece of the pie to be clickable, and once clicked, take me to a new page.

For example, the pie might have 3 pieces **(1, 2, 3)** and when user clicks on **1**, it will take him/her to
https://example.com/page?selected=**1**

I'm wondering what's the best way to go about this? Should I configure the pie's autoEl or implement an onClick function or is there a better way? I'm kind of new to Extjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to add a listener for itemmousedown when you define your pie chart series. From there there should be a way to determine which section was clicked on and open a dynamic url. Post code if you want more specific help!

Check out this question:
[ExtJS How to add a click event to Pie Chart pieces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965510/extjs-how-to-add-a-click-event-to-pie-chart-pieces)

Comment: Thanks, this is probably what I'll end up doing. I just wasn't sure if this was good practice to manually modify the URL instead of building it into the component...